# Heroku environment variable not accessible, instead getting <%= ENV['MY_Setting'] %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3

Have configuration in *aws_setting.yml* for different environments, as:

```html
local: &local_settings
  enable_setting: true

heroku: &heroku_settings
  enable_setting: <%= ENV['MY_SETTING'] %>

test:
  <<: *local_settings

development:
  <<: *local_settings

staging:
  <<: *heroku_settings
```

In heroku added MY_SETTING *kvp* in staging's **Config Vars**

Loaded settings during initialization:

```
S3_SETTING = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/aws_setting.yml")[Rails.env]
```

Now after deployment to staging, instead of getting value for `S3_Setting['enable_setting']` as `true` or `false`, receiving '<%= ENV['MY_SETTING'] %>' as text.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're just loading YAML. You also need to parse the content as ERB to get the value extrapolated.

```
YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("#{::Rails.root}/config/aws_setting.yml")).result)[Rails.env]
```